# How to set atributes throught reflexion

Tags: java, reflection

I have map of `<String, Object>:`

```
params={
  dateOfBirthTo=23.05.2013,
  lastName=bbb, ssn=aa-ccc-ddd,
  gender=MALE,
  dateOfBirthFrom=03.05.2013,
  firstName=aaa
}
```

Then I have form which contains variable from this map. How I can create new form with this value through reflection?

Something like:

```
SimpleForm form = new SimpleForm();

Map<String, Object> parameters = request.getParams();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
  // fill form
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Apache Commons BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/)

```
SimpleForm form = new SimpleForm();

Map<String, Object> parameters = request.getParams();
for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : parameters.entrySet()) {
    BeanUtils.setProperty(form, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
}
```

Comment: it should work i think. iirc you need to have setters for every property you want to set.

Comment: yes it works however I have one problem. Gender in my class is Enum not string si I have exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot invoke org.sample.model.Person.setGender on bean class 'class org.sample.model.Person' - argument type mismatch - had objects of type "java.lang.String" but expected signature "org.sample.model.PersonGender" Do you know how to solve it ?

Comment: you could provide a setter that takes a `String` and than check the value of the string and call the regular setter with the appropriate enum value